# TYPO3-Backend with one domain

Tags: typo3

I have a current TYPO3 with several domains. But now I want only one domain to be accessible via the TYPO3 backend. The other domains should then redirect to one URL.

I couldn't find anything in the TYPO3 documentation. Or did I miss something. I would probably have to solve it via httacess, right?

Comment: I think you won't found that in the TYPO3 Docs. That should be possible with a RewriteCond and RewriteRule in .htaccess file if you on an apache Web server. For nginx there will be something similar but not with an .htaccess file. Search for rewrite rules depending on your webserver.

Comment: @Karsten maybe create your comment as answer, eventually with at least a pseudo htaccess ruleset ? That way the questioner has the ability to mark the answer as the solution.